# How to force displaying specific dates on DateTimeAxis

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, charts

Is it possible to force the display of grid lines on the chart with the dates for the extreme data points?

I've tried almost every configuration of following Chart DateTimeAxis properties: `IntervalType`, `Interval`, `Minimum` and `Maximum` but I wasn't satisfied with the result.

Setting properties `Minimum` and `Maximum` didn't solve the problem.

For instance (`IntervalType="Days" , Interval="4" , Minimum="1/1/2010" , Maximum="1/31/2010"`):

[image: An example chart]

If I'm lucky I will generate some random data where only one extreme point will have the date with grid line.

Does somebody have an idea how to solve the problem mentioned above?

**Edited to add**
I added a bounty to this question since I really need a fast solution for this issue.

I am binding a series of specific  pairs to my chart and I'd like to display excactly those given DateTime values on the x-axis.
Since these are usually dates like 6/30/11, 6/30/12 and so on, I can't use the Interval/IntervalType properties because adding 1 year or 365 days to 6/30/11 doesn't necessarily result in 6/30/12.

So what I need to do is either disable the "automatic axis label generation" of the DateTime axis or use another axis type.
LinearAxis doesn't work because it expects double values and CategoryAxis is not an option because it displays the axis labels between two tickmarks instead of underneath them.

I am very grateful for any help!

To be perfectly clear, here is what axis labels I need (taken from another chart component):
[image]

This is what I get so far with the Silverlight 4 Toolkit:
[image]

€: I also opened a [thread](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/234753.aspx/1?Show%20specific%20dates%20on%20DateTimeAxis) in the official Silverlight Toolkit Support Forums.

Comment: Which chart control are you using?

Comment: Can you also show some example data which demonstrates the extreme you're refering to

Comment: @Derek Lakin - I'm using Microsoft Silverlight toolkit (System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll, v3.0.0.0)

Comment: @Matt Lacey - I wasn't  precise enough . I mean- extreme points on the x-axis.  For data I've showed on the image, which are : 1/1/2010 and 1/31/2010. These days I've set as Minimum and Maximum. As you can see only 1/1/2010 has grid line with date but 1/31/2010 no longer has.

Comment: I know this question is old but have you ever been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The vertical lines are set where you specify an interval.

There is no vertical line for the data for 1/31/2010 as it does not fall on an interval.

Comment: Yes that's true in this specific example which I've showed you. I'm looking for the solution where on the chart always will be grid line with date for the first and last data point. The number of data points on the chart doesn't matter.