# Windows Phone Chart - initialize datetimeaxis

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, windows-phone-7, charts, mvvm-light

Anyone tried to use a DateTimeAxis with MVVM on a WP7?
When I set up my chart, at startup there is no data available and then I get following result:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_SmOd7jMPAt4/TWbTkDDbPPI/AAAAAAAAEFY/4LXRE49D-yY/s800/Windows%20Phone%20Emulator_2011-02-24_22-41-31.png

But when I populate the binded chart data I get following result:

https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/_SmOd7jMPAt4/TWbTkOWbvoI/AAAAAAAAEFU/8MEI0lDW16k/s800/Windows%20Phone%20Emulator_2011-02-24_22-42-21.png

So my question, can I hide the labels ( through MVVM ) at startup? Or is there another way to get some nicer representation when there is no data?

Other question, I would also love to set the date labels fixed ( like in this question: [Stackoverflow chart date question unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811803/how-to-force-displaying-specific-dates-on-datetimeaxis-silverlight-charting-wp7)

Comment: Maybe for 'good' reference, even though the question is not yet answered. I solved it by using another charting object! Called AM Charts : http://blog.amcharts.com/2010/11/amcharts-quick-charts-in-windows-phone.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered setting the values to zero instead of not having any values?

Comment: I do need to re-look at the code to be sure, but I think the 'object' passed to the chart was initialized. ( Meaning strings are empty,  ints are 0, etc... ) But this question is already old, so I'm not 100% sure anymore.